# SQL Database MaxSize higher than total drive capacity/space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I received a SQL database backup that I need to restore that is only about 1.5GB, but the MaxSize is several hundred GB. The PC/server that I need to process the data on this backup only has a 250GB hard drive, so I'm unable to restore it there, and from my research it doesn't seem like there's a way to alter the maxsize before restoring.

I do have a second PC with enough space to restore the DB, but will need to have the db restored on the primary PC in the end to process the data.

Is there any way to restore a DB without enough space for the MaxSize? Alternatively, is there a way to reduce the MaxSize once the DB is restored on the secondary PC?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Max size is not a requirement. I guess you are confusing file size with max size. File size is reqired. You can shrink the file before backup. Or restore where there is space, shrink and then producera a new backup.